# emacs won't start due to "No fonts match `Inconsolata-12'"

Tags: linux, emacs, fonts, centos, xorg

Several weeks ago, I tried to customize my default font face Emacs 21.4.1 running on CentOS 5.5, and now emacs won't start.

emacs will start with the `-fn` flag. However, I can't find where Inconsolata-12 is specified in any of my configuration files, i.e. `.emacs.`

I also deleted my `.Xresources` file. The directory `.emacs.d` is empty.

Contents of my `.emacs` file:

```
(custom-set-variables
  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom -- don't edit or cut/paste it!
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 '(auto-compression-mode t nil (jka-compr))
 '(case-fold-search t)
 '(current-language-environment "UTF-8")
 '(default-input-method "rfc1345"))
(custom-set-faces
  ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom -- don't edit or cut/paste it!
  ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 )
```

Here's what the "customize face" menu looks like for "default" (when I start emacs with -fn)

[image: emacs customize default face screenshot]

Where can I look / what other configurations should I be investigating to resolve this issue?

Comment: What did you do when you "tried to customize [your] default font face"? It would help to know what files you messed around with. Also, you should first try moving your .emacs into a backup folder and see if emacs still tries to use that font.

Comment: I don't remember exactly, that's the problem. Moving aside .emacs has the same result. I will post a screenshot of what the "customize default face" looks like when I start with -fn

Answer (score 0):

There might be something in your .emacs-lisp directory. In any case, I would just reset the font in .emacs. For example:

```
(set-default-font "-apple-Monaco-normal-normal-normal-*-14-*-*-*-*-0-iso10646-1")
```

You can use xfontsel to get the correct font definition line.